# Interface vs static abstract class, when declaring a parcelable listener

Tags: java, android, interface, listener, abstract-class

I have a `DialogFragment` which provides a `Parcelable` listener so the caller can receive a callback when the user clicks one of the buttons to close the dialog (it needs to be `Parcelable` in order to be stored in the arguments `Bundle`).

At first, I declared it as an `interface`, like this:

```
public class EditTrackDialogFragment extends AppCompatDialogFragment {

    public interface OnEditTrackDialogListener extends Parcelable{
        public abstract void onSave(TrackData trackData);
        public abstract void onCancel(TrackData trackData);
    }

    // ...

}
```

...and then implemented it like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // ...

    private EditTrackDialogFragment.OnEditTrackDialogListener onEditTrackDialogListener = new EditTrackDialogFragment.OnEditTrackDialogListener() {
        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSave(TrackData trackData) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Track saved");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel(TrackData trackData) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Edit cancelled");
        }
    };

}
```

But I thought it just didn't seem right that the instantiator should need to deal with the implementation of the `Parcelable` interface. So I tried declaring the listener as an abstract class, which implements `Parcelable` itself, like this:

```
public class EditTrackDialogFragment extends AppCompatDialogFragment {

    public static abstract class OnEditTrackDialogListener implements Parcelable{
        public abstract void onSave(TrackData trackData);
        public abstract void onCancel(TrackData trackData);

        public OnEditTrackDialogListener() {

        }

        protected OnEditTrackDialogListener(Parcel in) {
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    // ...

}
```

...and provided a concrete implementation like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // ...

    private EditTrackDialogFragment.OnEditTrackDialogListener onEditTrackDialogListener = new EditTrackDialogFragment.OnEditTrackDialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSave(TrackData trackData) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Track saved");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel(TrackData trackData) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Edit cancelled");
        }
    };

}
```

In my opinion this is much cleaner and it feels more logical that the `DialogFragment`, which provides the listener "interface", is the one who should deal with the implementation of `Parcelable`. Otherwise I would have to provide those implementations every time I implement the listener, which just seems silly since they are always the same, not to mention the code gets more cluttered.

Anyway, my question is which approach is "best practice"? All answers I've managed to dig up on SO seem to stick to the first approach, but is there any good reason not to go with the (in my opinion "better") second approach?

Answer (score 0):

one thing:

**you will not get rid of Parcelable implementation if you inherit from abstract class because you still need CREATOR :)**

in my opinion your approach if you create lots of inherited classes from abstract parcelable could spare your time - one of goals of object oriented language is to reuse :)

and i like to have less job so i create some abstract parcelables

I can share with you with example from mines:

https://gist.github.com/c3ph3us/496d82751de74cae46f6d2aad2f11e71

*Are your sure? It seems to be working just fine as it is. Also, in the comment to this answer someone says that a creator isn't needed for an interface; is it still needed for an abstract listener class which doesn't contain any member variables? – BadCash*

example implementation of abstract parcelable with creator:

https://gist.github.com/c3ph3us/1ca07c497492b322bf02d01906796471

**YES - you need to provide creator in implementation of abstract class**

```
public interface Parcelable {

 ...

 /**
 * Interface that must be implemented and provided as a public CREATOR
 * field that generates instances of your Parcelable class from a Parcel.
 */
public interface Creator<T> {
    /**
     * Create a new instance of the Parcelable class, instantiating it
     * from the given Parcel whose data had previously been written by
     * {@link Parcelable#writeToParcel Parcelable.writeToParcel()}.
     * 
     * @param source The Parcel to read the object's data from.
     * @return Returns a new instance of the Parcelable class.
     */
    public T createFromParcel(Parcel source);

    /**
     * Create a new array of the Parcelable class.
     * 
     * @param size Size of the array.
     * @return Returns an array of the Parcelable class, with every entry
     * initialized to null.
     */
    public T[] newArray(int size);
}
```

*Can you explain why I need to implement the Creator interface? It seems to work perfectly fine without it? – BadCash*

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.Creator.html

pleas do some research :) try this and give me a hint if you can do it :) without creator

```
 public class ClassC implements Parcelable  {
     // no CREATOR 

    String test

    public ClassC(Parcel parcel) {
         test = parcel.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
         dest.writeString(test)
    }
}
```

classA - Activity onCreate

```
 Context.startActivity(new Intent(Context,ClassB.class)
                             .putExtra("KEY", new ClassC("TEST"))
                      );
```

ClassC - Activity onCreate

```
    Parcelable parcelable = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("KEY");
```

if you pass first test then try :

```
   Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
   parcel.writeParcelable(new ClassC("TEST"),0);
   Parcelable reRead = parcel.readParcelable(ClassC.class.getClassLoader());
```

and give me a result of this  :)

> ```
> do you know what is Parcel ? what is Binder ?
> ```

if it fails then start to redeem yourself by reading this :

```
/**
 * Container for a message (data and object references) that can
 * be sent through an IBinder.  A Parcel can contain both flattened data
 * that will be unflattened on the other side of the IPC (using the various
 * methods here for writing specific types, or the general
 * {@link Parcelable} interface), and references to live {@link IBinder}
 * objects that will result in the other side receiving a proxy IBinder
 * connected with the original IBinder in the Parcel.
 * ...
 **/
 public final class Parcel {


     ... 

    /**
     * Read and return a new Parcelable from the parcel.  The given class loader
     * will be used to load any enclosed Parcelables.  If it is null, the default
     * class loader will be used.
     * @param loader A ClassLoader from which to instantiate the Parcelable
     * object, or null for the default class loader.
     * @return Returns the newly created Parcelable, or null if a null
     * object has been written.
     * @throws BadParcelableException Throws BadParcelableException if there
     * was an error trying to instantiate the Parcelable.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public final <T extends Parcelable> T readParcelable(ClassLoader loader) {
       Parcelable.Creator<?> creator = readParcelableCreator(loader);
       if (creator == null) {
           return null;
       }
       if (creator instanceof Parcelable.ClassLoaderCreator<?>) {
         Parcelable.ClassLoaderCreator<?> classLoaderCreator =
             (Parcelable.ClassLoaderCreator<?>) creator;
         return (T) classLoaderCreator.createFromParcel(this, loader);
       }
       return (T) creator.createFromParcel(this);
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: Are your sure? It seems to be working just fine as it is. Also, in the comment to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31455559/930640) someone says that a creator isn't needed for an `interface`; is it still needed for an abstract listener class which doesn't contain any member variables?

Comment: Can you explain _why_ I need to implement the Creator interface? It seems to work perfectly fine without it?