# How to Create CREATOR inside interface which extends Parcelable?

Tags: java, android

On the first attempt, app is working fine. But after recreate of HomeActivity I am facing Exception **android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called CREATOR on class**

Now I am Confused about how and where to create CREATEOR?

Here is my interface.

```
public interface OnRefreshListener extends Parcelable { 
    void refresh();
}
```

Here is my activity.

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private OnRefreshListener refreshListener;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    refreshListener = new OnRefreshListener() {

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

         @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {}

        @Override
        public void refresh() {
            // my code
        }
    };
  }
}
```

Here is my Fragment

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {

public static TestFragment newInstance(OnRefreshListener refreshListener) {
 TestFragment testFragment = new TestFragment();
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putParcelable("onRefreshListener",refreshListener);
 testFragment.setArguments(bundle);
 return testFragment;
}
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: in what strange scenario do you need a parcelable listener?

Comment: To set Arguments for my fragment through bundle I need It @Tim castelijns

Comment: why do you need to pass a listener to a fragment through a bundle?

Comment: I just gave the sample of code. Real Code is different but the scenario is the same.

Comment: if the scenario is the same then my question remains - why are you passing listeners through bundles?

Comment: You can refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26904955/passing-listeners-via-bundle-in-alertdialogfragment-is-it-possible

Comment: I don't want to read all of that. I want you to explain what you're trying to do

Comment: see I have a 3 fragment in viewpager and in each fragment have a button to refresh so if anyone of fragment's button click then all the 3 fragments should be refreshed at once. I just call the method from a fragment and during implementation I just resetting an adapter. So hope you got scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Your listener should not implement Parcelable.
Remove that and your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have used Parcelable in wrong way, it is for parsing data between android components. Please read [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html). So do not extend listeners with Parcelable interface.

If you want an easy way to update other fragments in ViewPager, I normally use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).

You can have a POJO like following;

```
public class UpdateViewPagerUIEvent() {
    // you can have any values you need to parse here
}
```

Then on your button click post event to bus;

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new UpdateViewPagerUIEvent());
```

then on other fragments listen to event;

```
@Subscribe
public void onViewPagerUIEvent(UpdateViewPagerUIEvent event) {
    // do what ever you want here
}
```

You can post and listen on same fragment if you have refresh buttons on all fragments